# Vim open file determined by external script

Tags: vim

I have a line in one of my functions

```
silent! exec "r!sh myScript '" . a.1 "'
```

this prints the output of myScript to the current buffer.

myScript outputs a single filename.  Instead of printing the filename to the buffer I'd like to open that file.

I've tried things like

```
silent! exec "open!sh myScript '" . a.1 "'
silent! exec "new!sh myScript '" . a.1 "'
let l:file = silent! exec "sh myScript '" . a.1 "'
    new l:file
```

but none seem to work.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the system() function in this way:

```
let path=system("myScript ... ")
let path=substitute(path,"\n","","g")
exec "edit" path
```

Note that the intermediate `substitute` command may be necessary to remove erroneous newline characters. If it isn't necessary, don't worry about it. Of course, instead of `edit` you can use `split` or `vsplit` etc to suit your needs.